# Is it possible to access opened gnome terminal session in text console?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, console, gnome-terminal

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. My desktop environment (compiz and unity) sometimes becomes frozen, which makes it difficult to save my work including text editing in emacs running in gnome terminal.

After I switch to a text console by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I know I can't access the running programs with GUI. But is it possible to access the opened programs in the gnome terminal session, so that I can access my emacs session that is running in the gnome terminal?

Comment: You can run emacs as a daemon and connect to it with `emacsclient`. Another option is to use `screen`.

Comment: The gnome terminal session **is** a running program with GUI. What do you mean by "you cannot access the running programs"?

Comment: @Anthon: I meant I can't access the running programs with GUI in a text console after Ctrl-Alt-F1.

Comment: @Tim so you don't want to access the gnome-terminal, just the programming running it. Your question was a bit self contradictory, I tried to make that less so.

Answer (score 1):

If this happens often, consider running your emacs session in the Gnome Terminal within`tmux`. That way you can connect from the console with `tmux attach` and save whatever needs saving.

If you don't use `tmux`, [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) can allow you to reconnect the emacs session to your console for further editing.

Setting emacs` autosave might help as well in case you have to reboot your system without being able to save.